# Assignment problems with simple random number generation in Modelica

Tags: algorithm, variables, random, modelica

I am relatively new to Modelica (Dymola-environment) and I am getting very desperate/upset that I cannot solve such a simple problem as a random number generation in Modelica and I hope that you can help me out.

The simple function `random` produces a random number between 0 and 1 with an input seed `seedIn[3]` and produces the output seed `seedOut[3]` for the next time step or event. The call
`(z,seedOut) = random(seedIn);`
works perfectly fine.

The problem is that I cannot find a way in Modelica to compute this assignment over time by using the `seedOut[3]` as the next `seedIn[3]`, which is very frustrating.

My simple program looks like this:

```
*model Randomgenerator
Real z;
Integer seedIn[3]( start={1,23,131},fixed=true), seedOut[3];
equation
  (z,seedOut) = random(seedIn);
algorithm
  seedIn := seedOut;

end Randomgenerator;*
```

I have tried nearly all possibilities with algorithm assignments, initial conditions and equations but none of them works. I just simply want to use `seedOut` in the next time step. One problem seems to be that when entering into the algorithm section, neither the initial conditions nor the values from the equation section are used.

Comment: Probably you need a when equation or statement with reinit(seedIn, seedOut);

Comment: You also might be interested in the [DLR Noise](https://github.com/DLR-SR/Noise) and [DLR Advanced Noise](https://github.com/DLR-SR/AdvancedNoise) libraries. Or search for `Noise` on http://impact.github.io/

Comment: More about random number generation in Modelica in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943950/generate-white-noise-in-modelica-systemmodeler)

Answer (score 1):

Using the 'sample' and 'reinit' functions the code below will calculate a new random number at the frequency specified in 'sample'. Note the way of defining the "start value" of seedIn.

```
model Randomgenerator

  Real seedIn[3] = {1,23,131};

  Real z;
  Real[3] seedOut;

equation 
  (z,seedOut) = random(seedIn);
  when sample(1,1) then
   reinit(seedIn,pre(seedOut));
  end when;

end Randomgenerator;
```

The 'pre' function allows the use of the previous value of the variable. If this was not used, the output 'z' would have returned a constant value. Two things regarding the 'reinint' function, it requires use of 'when' and requires 'Real' variables/expressions hence seedIn and seedOut are now defined as 'Real'.

The simple "random" generator I used was:

```
function random

  input Real[3] seedIn;

  output Real z;
  output Real[3] seedOut;

algorithm 
  seedOut[1] :=seedIn[1] + 1;
  seedOut[2] :=seedIn[2] + 5;
  seedOut[3] :=seedIn[3] + 10;

  z :=(0.1*seedIn[1] + 0.2*seedIn[2] + 0.3*seedIn[3])/(0.5*sum(seedIn));

end random;
```

Surely there are other ways depending on the application to perform this operation. At least this will give you something to start with. Hope it helps.