# Random function in Modelica

Tags: random, modelica

Hello，I need a function as random in C language. Maybe you will say that i can call C function, but the effect is not the same in visual c++ tool. So, I need your help.
thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36265293/assignment-problems-with-simple-random-number-generation-in-modelica

Comment: Thanks, but i want it works like c: int res=random()%100;

Answer (score 3):

See the Noise library:

https://github.com/DLR-SR/Noise

It has some models and functions to generate random numbers.

Comment: Thanks, but i want it works like c:   int res=random()%100;

Comment: http://book.xogeny.com/behavior/functions/external/                  I implemented it by C languge

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Dymola`, you can use the function `rand()`:

```
model rand_model
  Real a(start=rand());
  Real b(start=rand());
equation 
  when (sample(1,1)) then
    a = rand();
    b = rand();
  end when;
end rand_model;
```

The function is not documented in the `Dymola` user manual and it is no part of the `modelica` standard. The output seems to be an integer between `0` and `32767`, seed seems to be constant.

Perhaps the implementation is given in the moutil.c file which is shipped with Dymola. But i'm not sure.